# navigationDestination with ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use the `navigationDestination` with `ForEach`. He is my scenario. I have a list of notification which I am passing into the `NotificationCelllView`. Now I have a action from `NotificationCelllView`  in which I have use the variable `moveToApptDetailView` to move on next screen which is `ApptDetailView`.

In simple words on click of `NotificationCelllView` action I want to move on the `ApptDetailView` page. Any better suggestion for this problem.

```
ForEach(viewModel.notifications.indices, id: \.self) { index in

    let notification = viewModel.notifications[index]

    NotificationCelllView(notification: notification) { type in
        switch type {
        case .refund:
            self.appointment = notification.appointment
            moveToApptDetailView.toggle()
        case .makePayment:
            debugPrint("notification makePayment pressed")
        case .none:
            debugPrint("notification none pressed")
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $moveToApptDetailView) {
        ApptDetailView(appt: $viewModel.notifications[index].appointment, viewModel: ApptHistoryViewModel())
            .hideNavigationBar
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you move the `.navigationDestination(...)` **outside** the `ForEach`. Note, you also need a wrapping `NavigationStack`. Note also, you are creating a new `ApptHistoryViewModel()` every time you call `ApptDetailView`, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: I have used the `NavigationStack ` . The issue is to move `navigationDestination ` outside it that I can access the **index**.

Comment: in that case, try declaring a `@State var selectedIndex` and set it, just before `moveToApptDetailView.toggle()`. Use that in your `navigationDestination`

Comment: But if i use the `.navigationDestination(...)` outside then app start freezing.

Comment: Show a [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducible code.
 
 Currently, your code does not show enough of the surrounding context to
understand your functionality. All I can do is guessing. 
 In any case, move the `.navigationDestination(...)` **outside** the `ForEach`.
 
 You may need a different version of navigationDestination, such as:
 `.navigationDestination(item: )`. Or you could use `NavigationStack(path: $path)`.
 
 Note that using `index` with `ForEach`,
 is not a good approach. Better to use `ForEach(viewModel.notifications)...`

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I recommend not using `indicies` because it will cause crashes if `notifications` is a dynamic array. Use model its self. You take a look at [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).

Secondly, you can use `NavigationPath` in this scenario.

So combine these things:

```swift
//Assuming this is model
struct Notification: Identifiable { ... }
```

```swift
//And this is SwiftUI View
@State var path = NavigationPath()
...
NavigationStack(path: $path) {
    ForEach(viewModel.notifications, id: \.id) { notification in
        NotificationCelllView(notification: notification) { type in
            switch type {
            case .refund:
                self.appointment = notification.appointment
                path.append(notification)
            case .makePayment:
                debugPrint("notification makePayment pressed")
            case .none:
                debugPrint("notification none pressed")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Notification.self) { notification in
        ApptDetailView(appt: notification.appointment, viewModel: ApptHistoryViewModel())
            .hideNavigationBar
    }
}
```